# get access to serializer validated data DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

all the django rest framework docs assume your going to instantly save the data. But what if I want access to the serializer data? What if I want to do something with it. Or if the serializer contains info other than what I need to save in a model?

is the `validated_data` attribute what we need?

So

```
validatedData = serializer.validated_data
userid = validatedData.get('id')
```

would work right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you are right, but remember the `validated_data` is generate only after you call `.is_valid()` method. For example:

```
serializer.is_valid()
# do it first ^^^^^
validatedData = serializer.validated_data
userid = validatedData.get('id')
```

You can look on example [saving-instances](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) in the docs

Comment: I don't understand how this is correct.  .is_valid() just returns True of False based on whether or not the data has been validated.  In the snippet you provided `userid` will still be `None`.

Comment: this method not only make validation it also (in the process)  insert data the values to the validated_data

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also,

```
userId = serializer.validated_data.pop('id')
```

Hope this will help.